# How can I prove that C' is the midpoint of $\overline{ A'B'}$?

Tags: geometry

[image: OT is the diameter of the circle. AC and BC are tangents to the circle.]

$\overline{OT}$ is the diameter of the circle. $AC$ and $BC$ are tangents to the circle.
In my attempt to prove, I have used the inversion with respect to the circle centred at $O$ with radius $\lvert OT\rvert$. Since $\alpha$ passes through the centre of inversion, $\alpha$ is inverted into a straight line, $\alpha’\perp OT$.
Next, consider the circle, $\beta$, centred at $C$ with radius $\lvert AC\rvert$.
Since $\beta$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$, and $\beta$ passes through $B$ and $A$, $\beta’$ passes through $B’$ and $A’$ and is orthogonal to $\alpha$’.
Hence, $\beta’$ is the unique circle centred at $C’$ passing through $B’$ and $A’$, orthogonal to $\alpha’$. Thus, $\lvert A’C’\rvert$ and $\lvert B’C’\rvert$ is the radius and thus $C’$ is the midpoint of $A’B’$. 
Is this prove sufficient to prove that $C’$ is the midpoint of $\overline{A’B’}$?

Comment: I think you should explain **why** the center of $\beta'$ is $C'$. I mean, it indeed is, but what is the reason?

Comment: @timon92 just asking are you that same guy who contributes with burii on AoPS?

Comment: Yes, I use the same nickname on aops.

Comment: Also, to show that $C'$ is the center of $\beta'$ you can make the following two observations. (1) $\beta$ is symmetric wrt $OC$, so $\beta'$ is also symmetric wrt $OC$. In particular the center of $\beta'$ lies on $OC$. (2) $\beta'$ is orthogonal to the line $\alpha'$, so the center of $\beta'$ lies on $\alpha'$. From these two observations it follows that $C'$ is the center of $\beta'$.

Comment: By the way you can solve the problem elementarily. Just draw a line parallel to $A'B'$ through $C$ and intersect it with lines $OA$, $OB$. Call the new points $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Angle chasing shows that $ACX$ and $BCY$ are isosceles thus  $OX=OA=OB=OY$. It follows that $C$ is the midpoint of $XY$ and so $C'$ is the midpoint of $A'B'$.

Answer (score 1):

So much is not required, i will give a proof without inversion. Note that $OC$ is the $O$ symmedian of $\Delta OAB$ and let $OC \cap \alpha=J$, then you have $(AB,OJ)=-1$. Projecting through perspectivity at $O$ on $TB'$, you have $(AB,OJ)=(A'B',OO \cap TB' C')=(A'B',\infty_{TB'}C')=-1$ implying your result.

Comment: i see! thanks so much for this!! however, do u know if my proof works?

Comment: I have edited my proof do check it

Comment: @SeanLee sorry it doesn't! But you could try to fix this most conditions seem to fit in.